# Caching strategy using Firestore on Android

Tags: android, firebase, caching, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

#### Context

I have and Android application that uses Firestore database. In the database I have a collection called *measurements*. Each measurement item has a *timestamp*, which represents the time when the measurement was taken. The items can not be updated. Only new measurements can be uploaded, and existing ones can be deleted. My app has a local database built by Room, and I'm trying to find an optimal way to cache everything here from Firestore.

#### What I've got so far

**Getting new items** - To get the newly uploaded measurements (uploaded by an other client), I just get the latest timestamp in the cache, and query the documents with newer timestamps. As it turned out this solution is not a good practice, see the problem description below.

**Getting deleted items** - When an item is deleted, it gets moved into a collection called *deleted_measurements*. The whole collection is queried by the app on each startup. If there are items in the query result that are also present in the cache, the item gets deleted from the cache as well. To limit the size of this collection, each item gets deleted permanently 120 days after it's replacement into the *deleted_measurements* collection.

#### My problem

A scenario which causes inconsistency between the cache and Firestore:

1. Client A creates 2 measurements, but for now only uploads the latest one with the newer timestamp.
2. Client B opens the app, which downloads the newly added item
3. Client A triggers the uploading of the first (older) measurement
4. Because of the caching logic described above, the first (older) item will not be downloaded by client B, as the timestamp is less than the latest one present in B's cache. This is inconsistency.

I was also thinking about adding an additional attribute to the items, e.g. *timestamp_of_upload* and base the caching on this, but here's my problem with that:

To upload new items into the collection, I use a [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager). This is because the app is often used in areas where the network quality is really bad, and I don't want the upload task to be cancelled when the app is closed by the user. This means that I can never exactly know when an item will be uploaded. I only know when the upload was triggered.

Any ideas, how can I overcome this?

Comment: I think this article [How to drastically reduce the number of reads when no documents are changed in Firestore?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-drastically-reduce-the-number-of-reads-when-no-documents-are-changed-in-firestore-8760e2f25e9e) might help.

Answer (score 0):

You have a very interesting approach. I'm not sure if you know it but I think [this](https://codeburst.io/read-and-cache-data-with-firebase-firestore-80fc5466168d) article would be very interesting for you.

Can't you enable the offline capabilities for firestore to avoid using the WorkManager? In my native Apps the `firestore` database is very reliable on bad and even missing network connections.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the article, I'll read that soon. In which aspect do you think my approach is interesting? You are right, I could use the firestore SDK only without WorkManager for uploading. However I'm not sure how it works when the app is killed. And unfortunately I would not be much further with it, because I wouldn't know the timestamp of successful upload in this case either.

Comment: I find the approach to only get the data that has a change interesting because it can massibely reduce the read amouont. I think that the android SDK of Firestore can handle App Kills and even restarts of the device (not only the app)